# How to merge 2 Observables and emit values based on specific conditions in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, observable

I have 2 `observables`,

```
const obsA = this.api.ObsA();
const obsB = this.api.ObsB();
```

and I want to `join` them into a `single observable`, that will `EMIT` values only following certain rules:

- -if it emits, it must `emit both values`, preferably as an `array`, first value: `arr[0]`, second value: `arr[1]`.
- -if `obsA` emits `NULL`, then I must run: `subjectObsB.next(null)`, setting the value of `obsB` to `NULL` as well, and emitting both `null` values.
- -if any of the 2 `observable` emits a `new value`, emit it right away along with the other `Observable's` latest emitted value. (of course
  applying the rules above first)

What is my best bet?

I tried following this route:

```
const mergedObs = merge(
      this.obsA().pipe(
        tap((s) => {
          if (s == null) this.api.resetObsB(null);
        })
      ),
      this.obsB()
    );
```

But it's not working, I'm missing some logic here I guess

Answer (score 0):

You can use `combineLatest` to merge two observables: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/combineLatest (note that the docs show each observable as an own param, but they must be passed as array)

```
combineLatest([obs1, obs2]).pipe(map(([val1, val2]) => {
  // not sure if this is the best solution, may trigger a subscriber twice
  if (val1 === null) {
    obs2.next(null);
    return [null, null];
  }
  return [val1, val2];
}).subscribe(([val1, val2]) => {

});
```

Or to pick up your code

```
const mergedObs = combineLatest(
  this.obsA().pipe(
    tap((s) => { if (s == null) this.api.resetObsB(null);})
  )),
  this.obsB()
);

mergedObs.subscribe(([latestValueFromObsA, latestValueFromObsB]) => {
  // do stuff
});
```

Comment: a note, this merged Observable will the go inside a combineLatest with other observable, so if I follow this approach, basically I will have a nested combineLatest, is that ok?

Comment: @AJ989 updated my awnser with your example code as well